# How can I avoid showing temporary values in <input>?

Tags: html, blazor

I created an input that only accepts multiples of 15 and 27. The code works but clicking the up/down arrows shows the not accepted values for a millisecond before the logic changes it to the accepted value.
Example: The current value is 15. After clicking the up arrow, the input first shows 16 and then changes it to 27.
How can I avoid this?

Here's my code:

**Index.razor**

```
<input type="number" @bind-value="@Foo">
```

**Index.razor.cs**

```
public partial class Index
{
    private int _foo = 500;

    private int Foo
    {
        get => _foo;
        set
        {
            if (value != _foo)
            {
                if (value > _foo)
                {
                    _foo = value;
                    while (_foo % 15 != 0 && _foo % 27 != 0)
                    {
                        _foo++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _foo = value;
                    while (_foo % 15 != 0 && _foo % 27 != 0)
                    {
                        _foo--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: How about adding some additional html attributes, like: `step="12" min="15" max="27"` ?

Comment: But min="15" and max="5000". So, from 15 to 27 you are right, step="12". But from 27 to the next possibility, which is 30, step="3". Of course, I could change step too, but step is only 3 when the user increases the value. It is 12 again, if the user decides to decrease the value (because 27-3=24 is not allowed).

Comment: My mistake, misread your question and thought you're just using these two values. The step attribute is fix, so no math is allowed, but you could update it using js, but that ignores the fact of .NET/Blazor to be able to code without js at all ;) Well, I guess you're limited to only a few options then, like replacing your logic with JS code that might be a bit faster and doesn't show the flickering. Also there might be an option to prefill a dropdownlist with your values or validate it only on submit, of course with a hint to your logic for that input field.

Comment: I could also update step with C# and use `step="@stepValue"`. But as mentioned, this is not possible, since "step up" and "step down" is mostly not the same and I cannot know, if the user increases or decreases the value. I do not know much JS, so, this is also not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've looked a bit more into this and it seems that the up and down arrows inside the input field are causing the problem. I've tested it with js and there's still some flickering that shows the next or previous number before applying the calculated number. While typing in your number or using the keyboard arrows-keys to increase or decrease them seems to work flawlessly.

> So this might not be caused by Blazor itself as JS also struggles

The best bet would be to hide these arrows/spinners for the number input and only allow the user to enter a number and/or use the arrow keys on the keyboard to change them.

Here's an example of how it could work in JS (Should be applicable in Blazor as they also added input events):

##### Hide arrows/spinners of input field:

```css
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
  
input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

Hint: Edit to your needs as it removes them on all number inputs.

##### Add your number input element

```html
<input type="number" min="15" max="5000" id="specialNumberInput"/>
```

##### Catch the input's events to calculate your values

```js
var currentValue = 500;

document.getElementById('specialNumberInput').onchange = function (event) {
  let minValue = parseInt(event.srcElement.getAttribute('min'));
  let maxValue = parseInt(event.srcElement.getAttribute('max'));
  let value = parseInt(event.srcElement.value);

  if(value > maxValue) {
    currentValue = maxValue;
    event.srcElement.value = currentValue;
    return;
  }

  if(value < minValue) {
    currentValue = minValue;
    event.srcElement.value = currentValue;
    return;
  }

  if (value > currentValue)
  {
    while (value % 15 != 0 && value % 27 != 0)
    {
      value++;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    while (value % 15 != 0 && value % 27 != 0)
    {
      value--;
    }
  }
  
  currentValue = value;
  event.srcElement.value = currentValue;
}
```

As mentioned above you could attach your Blazor code to the "onchange" event of your input and run your logic to calculate next or previous values. As js also flickers, removing the selection arrows/spinners might then also work flawlessly with Blazor.

Comment: Thanks for the time you spent with this. Normally, the first thing I do with inputs is removing the spinners. But in this case I want them, because I do not await the user to know that after e.g. 105 the next possible number he can type is 108 (=4*27). The up and down arrows on the keyboard are not available when using a mobile device. So, this time I need the spinners. I will probably do the exact opposite and use `onkeydown="return false"` on the input what does not allow a keyboard input.